# Why <xsl:value-of select="1"/> returns 1?

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xpath

I'm transforming XML to HTML using a XSLT Stylesheet. The tansformation engine is provided by [Apache Xalan](https://xalan.apache.org/) (Version 2.7.0). A Sax Parser is configured to be used.

If

```
<xsl:value-of select="1"/>
```

is used to transform

```
<element>
    <hello>Hello World</hello>
</element>
```

**Output**

> 1

According to https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_value_of.asp the xsl:value-of-Tag extracts the value of a selected node based on the given XPath Expression.

- Why is the output 1 though there is no node 1?
- How does this simple transformation work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`xsl:value-of`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#value-of) instruction returns the result of evaluating the **expression** contained in its `select` attribute (after converting the result to a string).

An [XPath expression](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#section-Expressions) can contain numbers, string literals, references to nodes or variables, function calls and operators. The expression `1` is evaluated as the number 1. There can be no node whose name is `1` (an element name cannot start with a digit).

Comment: So the xpath engine does not parse the xml?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. XPath is a language, not an engine. XPath looks at the XML tree (after it has been parsed) and provides means to address specific parts of it.

Comment: I'm talking about the libary which processes the xpath expression.

Comment: Let me ask the question more accurate. Does the xpath processing libary parse the xml, in case a xpath expression "1".

Comment: If you're talking about the XSLT processor, it too works on the XML tree after it has been parsed. But I still don't see how this connects to your original question. The processor knows that `123` is a number, because it meets the [lexical structure](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#exprlex) of a number. In the same manner it knows that `+` is an operator and `root` is a node.

Answer (score 0):

By using the code

`<xsl:value-of select="1"/>`

you're essentially telling it to return the literal value "1".

To retrieve the value within the element it would be more like the following:

`<xsl:value-of select="hello"/>`